# Delay between event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an event listener detecting when I scroll, and when I scroll a transform happens in CSS to a `div`, but I want a delay so you can't perform the event right after it just happened.

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {

  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    wheel.style.transform = "transform";
  } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
    wheel.style.transform = `transform * -1`;
  } else {
    return;
  }

  //I tried setTimeout but it didn't do anything for me, maybe I'm using it wrong?

  setTimeout((event) => {
    wheel.style.transform
    console.log("hi")
  }, 1000)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setTimeout()` for the real action that you just want to do

In your current code,it just let the wheel event after 100 ms to bind it, once it binded and the event trigger,it will execute immediately

```
// this will just make the event bind after 100ms to work
setTimeout((event) => {
    wheel.style.transform
    console.log("hi")
  }, 100)
```

We can change it as below:

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  console.log("click event:" + new Date())
  
  setTimeout(()=> {
      console.log("click event timeout:" + new Date())
      if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        //wheel.style.transform = "transform";  
      } else if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        //wheel.style.transform = `transform * -1`;
      } else {
        return;
      }
  },3000)
})
```

Comment: Awesome it worked, but the delay is before the events, is there anyway to add a delay after the event happened? As of right now the event can happen over and over without pauses.

Comment: @AidanWilliams just need to invoke `setTimeout` after your own code